# Dynamically change mask on bootstrap-inputmask.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input-mask

I am using bootstrap-inputmask.js to make my input masks on textboxes. I have this specific textbox where there are two possible masks and the current mask is defined by a checkbox. I have made this script using jQuery:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(
        $("#phoneCheckbox").change(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#phoneTextBox").attr("data-mask", "(99) 9999-9999");
            } else {
                $("#phoneTextBox").attr("data-mask", "(99) 999-999-999");
            }
        }));    
    </script>
```

However this is not working: the property data-mask of #phoneTextBox is changing properly, but the mask on the textbox itself does not change! Anyone could help?

Comment: If the script reads the `data-mask` attribute only once at initialization and doesn’t provide an API to update the mask at runtime – then it’ll probably be easiest if you use _two_ input fields, one visible and one hidden, and toggle between those two depending on your checkbox. (And maybe toogle their `disabled` state as well if you don’t want the currently not “active” one not to submit with the rest of the form.)

Comment: It works. I would accept it as answer if you had actually posted as answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the script reads the `data-mask` attribute only once at initialization and doesn’t provide an API to update the mask at runtime – then it’ll probably be easiest if you use *two* input fields, one visible and one hidden, and toggle between those two depending on your checkbox.

(And maybe toggle their `disabled` state as well if you don’t want the currently not “active” one not to submit with the rest of the form.)